# Basic sequences

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Nowadays, we know that there exist Banach spaces without unconditional basic sequences. Do we know if something a bit milder holds? Namely, is that true each non-reflexive Banach space contains a normalised basic sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that for each $(t_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in c_0$ the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty t_n x_n$$

is convergent in this space? Has anyone studied this sort of basic sequences?

Comment: Something is missing, for if $t_n=||x_n||=1$ the series can't converge...


Comment: Right, the crucial assumption was missing :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Banach spaces that admit such a sequence are the Banach spaces that contain a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$.  Look at, e.g., the beginning part of the book of Albiac-Kalton.